# MVC - Is storing API Token on the Client Session a valid rest aproach?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I have a MVC4 application used to comunicate with an API, 
this application get a Bearer Token from the API on the first login,
 then the token must be sent to the api on each request.

Just to be clear, it's like this :

[MVC Website] <-> [API] <-> [SQL database]
Session with token would be on the MVC website, not the api...

As such, since the MVC4 application is the client of the API,
 is it a good approach to store this **Token** in the Session of the MVC4 wesite?

No exchange is made with the API exept the request, so it's still stateless, or am i missing something?

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have reasons to store token in ASP.NET MVC client application session, you can do it. I would say, session (and maybe database) is the best place to store API auth token.

The only problem you have to handle is token expiration.